# How to use a bean comparator to sort a list in which Integer values are stored as String?

Tags: java, list, sorting

Following is my bean

```
Person:
String name;
String age;
String designation;
```

I have used BeanComparator to sort my list in runtime like this

```
if (sortOrd.equals("asc")) {
        Collections.sort(list, new BeanComparator(sortByProperty));
    } else if (sortOrd.equals("desc")) {
        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder(new BeanComparator(
                sortByProperty)));

    }
```

If I want to sort by age, Then for the input 10, 35, 100, 25 it gets sorted as 10, 100, 25, 35 as it is stored as String.

Is there any way to fetch the correct result? Please help me out.

Comment: Why don't you declare age as an `int`?

Comment: just parse it to Integer

Comment: As has already been asked: why is age a string? If you store numbers only then make it an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a custom comperator to BeanComparator. Create one that parses as 
Integer and compares them.

```
  Collections.sort(list, new BeanComparator(sortByProperty), new Comparator<String>() {
    int compare(String s, String s2) {
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
return i1 - i;
}
});
```

Something like that (Not tested and you need some checks before parsing).

Comment: You can't pass multiple comparators to `Collections.sort()`. Would need a decorator or similar.

Comment: No, you just nest comparators ;)